How can I add a file column to a Dataverse table?
Everything I search for seems to indicate that this is possible. It says to add a column and select the "File" type, but there is no "File" type listed to add, just the basic data types. Copilot says to ensure that my environment allows file columns, but I can't find any setting that seems related. I see descriptions indicating that the file column will be a text column related to a separate attachments table. It all makes sense except for finding the option to make it happen.

The File column type is listed here


I appreciate the response, but my point was that the "File" type was not listed in that drop-down. I finally figured out why. I did have to enable it as indicated in the Copilot answer. At the moment, I can't remember exactly where I went to do that, but it wasn't intuitive.
